# Export version history from a List (Microsoft List) | Get KPIs

Tags: list, sharepoint, export

I have a list in Microsoft List that is used as a tracking tool for work management. We have status, category of issue, people to be assigned, due date.

To track KPIs, we need to have some sort of export (csv) with the infos that can be found in version history of each item of the list.

For instance, we need to know how many items have been in status "published" in november, how many in october, etc.

How many have been modified by "..." and by "..."

And the most important indicator would be the number of days until an item has been open -> closed. By "open" I mean created. By "closed" I mean the last modification done on it .

NB : We don't have Power Automate but we can use Power BI

I tried the basic CSV export, it only has the column from my list, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that can export SharePoint List Item Version History to Excel using PowerShell.The reference code in the article below can export the creator and creation time of each version, and you can also add other fields as needed.

Reference: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/sharepoint-version-history-export-to-excel.html